# Socket versus URL website access

Tags: java, httpclient, lwp

I have a Java application which opens an existing company's website using the `Socket` class:

```
Socket sockSite;
InputStream inFile = null;
BufferedWriter out = null;

try
{
    sockSite = new Socket( presetSite, 80 );
    inFile = sockSite.getInputStream();
    out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(sockSite.getOutputStream()) );
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    ...
}

out.write( "GET " + presetPath + " HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n" );
out.flush();
```

I would read the website with the stream `inFile` and life is good.

Recently this started to fail. I was getting an `HTTP 301` "site has moved" error but no moved-to link. The site still exists and responds using the same original HTTP reference and any web browser. But the above code comes back with the `HTTP 301`.

I changed the code to this:

```
URL url;
InputStream inFile = null;

try
{
    url = new URL( presetSite + presetPath );
    inFile = url.openStream();
}
catch ( IOException e )
{
    ...
}
```

And read the site with the original code from `inFile` stream and it now works again.

This difference doesn't just occur in Java but it also occurs if I use Perl (using `IO::Socket::INET` approach opening the website port 80, then issuing a `GET` fails, but using `LWP::Simple` method `get` just works). In other words, I get a failure if I open the web page first with port 80, then do a `GET`, but it works fine if I use a class which does it "all at once" (that just says, "get me web page with such-and-such an HTTP address").

I thought I'd try the different approaches on `http://www.microsoft.com` and got an interesting result. In the case of opening port 80, followed by issuing the `GET /...`, I received an `HTTP 200` response with a page that said, "Your current user agent 
In one case, I tried the "port 80" open followed by `GET /` on `www.microsoft.com` and I received an `HTTP 200` response page that said, "Your current user agent appears to be from an automated process...". But if I use the second method (`URL` class in Java, or `LWP` in Perl) I simply get their web page.

So my question is: *how does the URL class (in Java) or the LWP module (in Perl) do its thing under the hood that makes it different from opening the website on port 80 and issuing a `GET`*?

Comment: If you want to implement a protocol yourself, you need to read the spec.  HTTP requires `\r\n`.

Comment: Servers may also want HTTP 1.1, as well as the `Host:` header.

Comment: @SLaks same problem occurs with HTTP 1.1. Also, I tried `\r\n` as well and had the same problem. It's actually what I had originally (yes, I did read that part of the spec - albeit quite some time ago) but for some reason I changed it in my attempt to figure out what was happening. I will, however, try it again to be sure.

Comment: Did you try the `Host:` header?

Comment: @SLaks OK, yeah, I'm a dummy. I should have gone back to the GET documentation. It's been so long since I had written these that I assumed they were correct in format. They'd been working up until literally the past couple of weeks. Adding the `Host:` to the socket case made it work. Thanks much. If you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most servers require the `Host:` header, to allow virtual hosting (multiple domains on one IP)

Comment: Thanks. I see that now. Oddly, as I mentioned, my scripts worked fine for a long, long time before starting to fail very recently. Even to the same server. That's what caused me to overlook the requirement for the `Host:` header item.

Comment: From what I can tell, when I had `HTTP/1.0` originally, that *may* have invoked some "leniency" on the part of the host (figuring things out heuristically for lack of a "Host" header). Thus, originally I happened to get away without the Host header. With `HTTP/1.1` it appears to be required.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a packet capturing software to see what's being sent when URL is used, you'll realize that there's a lot more than just "GET /" being sent. All sorts of additional header information are included. If a server gets just a simple "GET /", it's easy to deduct that it can't be a very sophisticated client on the other end.

Also, HTTP 1.0 is "outdated", the current version is 1.1.

Comment: Thanks. I get the same problem if I use `HTTP 1.1` in the request. The idea that `URL` is doing a GET plus a lot more I could definitely understand. I was curious what "a lot more" really is. I can see if I can find a packet capture program and figure some of it out.

Answer (score 0):

Java URL implementation delegates to [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) if it starts with "http:"